# Running c++ in terminal and got "fatal error: 'iostream' file not found"

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++ and when I ran the script

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  cout << "Another message";
  return 0;
}
```

in the terminal `cpp test.cpp`, I got this error message:

```
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I am using clang as compiler on Mac. The text editor is VS Studio code. The strange thing is that when I run the script in VS Studio code via the extension "Code Runner", it works just fine.

I know there are several other similar questions being asked, but I cannot understand how they solved the question. Can anyone give me some step-by-step instructions? Thank you so much !

Comment: How about installing `libc++-dev`?

Comment: `cpp` is the preprocessor. What happens if you use the compiler instead?

Answer (score -2):

It turns out that just adding `gcc test.cpp  -lstdc++` in the terminal solves the problem.

Comment: Adding `-lstdc++` will _not_ fix the problem with `'iostream' file not found`. What compiler did you use? Provide the complete compilation command.

Comment: @Ted I use gcc.

Comment: So, use `g++` instead and you won't have to add `-lstdc++`. `gcc` is good for plain C programs. C++ requires a few extra libraries as you noticed. Do this: `g++ test.cpp`